# Mysql select with sub (row, row - 1)

Tags: mysql

how to select user_id, **SUB(row, row - 1)** from **users** where user_id=@userid
my table **users** with id 1, 3, 4, 10, 11, 23...(not ++)

```
--id---------user_id------unixtime--
635918634   1529906793  1374253286
635918635   1529906793  1374253287
635957809   1529906793  1374253583
635957810   1529906793  1374253883
635957811   1529906793  1374254183
```

I wish

```
--id-----------user_id--------unixtime-------**SUB(row, row -1)**
635918634   1529906793  1374253286      0
635918635   1529906793  1374253287      1   
635957809   1529906793  1374253583      296     
635957810   1529906793  1374253883      300
635957811   1529906793  1374254183      300
```

With **SUB(row, row -1)**: (unixtime row - unixtime near row before)

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question with more information. The question reads `row - 1` and the description reads `row + 1`.

Comment: What does `SUB(row, row+1)` mean?

Comment: I edit post for explain, please view and help me ^^,

Comment: you're selecting `SUB(row, row + 1)`, and in your table you've got `SUB(row, row - 1)`. I think you can see why we're confused.

Comment: Even if they were the same, it still doesnt' make any sense. Are you trying to make it auto increment? I can't see how those 5 rows would generate `0`, `1`, `296`, `300` and `300` (again)?

Comment: I wish result: 0, 1, 296, 300 and 300 with one query

Answer (score 0):

Using user variables to add a sequence (using 2 different staring sequence numbers), then joining on sequence

```
SELECT Sub1.id, Sub1.user_id, Sub1.unixtime, Sub1.unixtime - IFNULL(Sub2.unixtime, 0)
FROM
(
    SELECT id, user_id, unixtime, @row = @row + 1 AS RowNum
    FROM SomeTable
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row = 1) t
    ORDER BY user_id, unixtime
) Sub1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, user_id, unixtime, @row = @row + 1 AS RowNum
    FROM SomeTable
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row = 0) t
    ORDER BY user_id, unixtime
) Sub2
ON Sub1.RowNum = Sub2.RowNum
```

(not tested)